# How can I make my Python code on Leetcode more faster?

Tags: python, performance

The problem:
Given an array of numbers nums, in which exactly two elements appear only once and all the other elements appear exactly twice. Find the two elements that appear only once.
Example:

```
Input:  [1,2,1,3,2,5]
Output: [3,5]
```

That`s my Code:

```
class Solution:
    def singleNumber(self, nums):

        single=set(nums)
        my_list_tek=list(single)
        z=[a for a in nums if not a in my_list_tek or my_list_tek.remove(a)]
        return [i for i in nums if not i in z]
```

Comment: At least use sets, but here you can use a bitmask to obtain these items.

Comment: So many unnecessary operations, for starters... Why 2 for loops? You can only loop once and count each value. Also, if you have a `set`, why do you make it a `list` and check if elements are `in` this list? This is a `O(n)` operation whereas if you just used the set you already had it'd be `O(1)`

Comment: Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

class Solution:
    def singleNumber(self, nums):
        single=set(nums)
        my_list_tek=list(single)
        z=[a for a in nums if not a in my_list_tek or my_list_tek.remove(a)]
        return [i for i in nums if not i in z]

def test1(data):
    return [x for x in range(len(data)) if data[x] not in data[:x] + data[x + 1:]]

def test2(data):
    return Solution().singleNumber(data)

def test3(data):
    d = Counter(data)
    return [k for k, v in d.items() if v == 1]
```

Let's see how they perform:

```
>>> in_data = [1,2,1,3,2,5]
>>> timeit.timeit("test1(in_data)", setup="from __main__ import test1, in_data", number=100000)
0.2761846099997456
>>> timeit.timeit("test2(in_data)", setup="from __main__ import test2, in_data", number=100000)
0.2404884940001466
>>> timeit.timeit("test3(in_data)", setup="from __main__ import test3, in_data", number=100000)
0.45264831800022876
```

Hmm, looks like you're not going too slow after all, and that Counter method is just terrible. Let's try with more data (maybe using Counter will catch up).

```
>>> in_data = [6, 93, 66, 34, 79, 3, 56, 92, 75, 6, 35, 2, 2, 59, 94, 61, 29, 97, 99, 58, 42, 99, 74, 94, 93, 98, 76, 73, 78, 42, 60, 68, 58, 70, 36, 16, 11, 43, 16, 47, 5, 79, 66, 28, 89, 41, 50, 16, 81, 23, 45, 4, 19, 91, 51, 33, 22, 24, 77, 42, 64, 20, 76, 71, 38, 5, 45, 14, 85, 93, 28, 11, 47, 89, 83, 85, 12, 89, 74, 29, 57, 51, 74, 84, 86, 84, 63, 86, 60, 68, 31, 35, 60, 53, 72, 49, 80, 69, 66, 44]
>>> timeit.timeit("test1(in_data)", setup="from __main__ import test1, in_data", number=10000)
2.0650007710000864
>>> timeit.timeit("test2(in_data)", setup="from __main__ import test2, in_data", number=10000)
0.9076229890001741
>>> timeit.timeit("test3(in_data)", setup="from __main__ import test3, in_data", number=10000)
0.14566440800035707
```

Why yes, indeed it does.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Counter` with list comprehension to speed up:

```
from collections import Counter
d = Counter([1,2,1,3,2,5])
[k for k,v in d.items() if v==1]

[3, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: @OsmanBabayigit Why removed acceptance it is indeed faster than all other methods check the other solution end part.

Answer (score 0):

```
dta = [1,2,1,3,2,5]
ctr = Counter(dta).most_common()
least2, least1 = ctr.pop(), ctr.pop()
print(least1[0], least2[0])
```

However useful collections and itertools are in the abstract, I've not found them to better than roll-your-own when you have domain specific knowledge.